# loops in headers or main file

Tags: c++, header

So I put a while loop in my header file and I wanted to connect it to my main.cpp but then my main.cpp is not playing it unless it is stated like in my header file. So I'm wondering if a while loop in the header even necessary? The assignment is to create a program that calculates the user's salary given her sales.

This is my header file:

```
class Salary
{
public:
Salary(){};
    Salary(double employeeSales, double employeeSalary)
    :sales{employeeSales},salary(employeeSalary)
    {
        while(employeeSales != -1)
        {
            salary = 200 + (.09 * sales);
        }
    }
void setSales(double employeeSales)
{
    sales = employeeSales;
}
void setSalary(double employeeSalary)
{
    salary = employeeSalary;
}

double getSales() const{return sales;}
double getSalary() const{return salary;}
private:
    double sales;
    double salary;
};
```

this is my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Salary.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Salary mySalary;
    double employeeSales;
    double employeeSalary;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Enter sales in dollars(-1 to quit): ";
    cin >> employeeSales;
    mySalary.setSales(employeeSales);

    while(true)
    {
        employeeSalary = 200 + (.09 * employeeSales);
        mySalary.setSalary(employeeSalary);
        cout << "Salary is: $" << mySalary.getSalary();
        cout << "Enter sales in dollars(-1 to quit): ";
        cin >> employeeSales;
        mySalary.setSales(employeeSales);
    }

}
```

However the while loop in main won't work unless i put while(employeeSales != -1)

Comment: "Won't work" means what?

Comment: Your second constructor is never used. So, adding `while(employeeSales != -1)` can't possible be preventing any failure.

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger and you'll see why your loop is never executed.

Comment: @GigaRohan why is the second constructor never used?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have your constructor handle garbage data (-1 as the argument), just create an if statement in the while-loop in main that breaks if the user entered -1.

```
while(true)
{
    employeeSalary = 200 + (.09 * employeeSales);
    mySalary.setSalary(employeeSalary);
    cout << "Salary is: $" << mySalary.getSalary();
    cout << "Enter sales in dollars(-1 to quit): ";
    cin >> employeeSales;
    if( employeeSales == -1)
    {
        cout << "Stopping program!" << endl;
        break; // exits the while loop
    }
    mySalary.setSales(employeeSales);
}
```

Doing this allows for a while-loop in your Salary constructor to be unnecessary, and should hopefully solve your issue.

Comment: it does. However my question is what does the while loop in the header do? is it even necessary because the program can still run without it.

Comment: @xx123 I'm pretty sure that the while loop in the header shouldn't be there. You can assign the salary variable without the conditional loop because with the solution above, you check for garbage data in your main.